# Ruby on Rails: Calling an instance method from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model

I've got a Match model and a Team model.
I want to run an instance method (written inside the Team model) after a Match has been saved. Here's what I've got.

#### team.rb

```
def goals_sum
  unless goal_count_cache
    goal_count = a_goals_sum + b_goals_sum
    update_attribute(:goal_count_cache, goal_count)
  end
  goal_count_cache
end
```

and it works. Now I need to run this whenever a match gets saved. So I tried this:

#### match.rb

```
after_save :Team.goals_sum
after_destroy :Team.goals_sum
```

And it doesn't work.
I know I'm missing something basic, but I still can't go through with it. Any tips?

Comment: Why don't you put that in `Match` then?

Comment: Does the match model has 2 relations to the teams playing the match? Like team_a and team_b?

Comment: @mliebelt - Yes, it has 2 relations: `belongs_to :team_a, :class_name => 'Team', :foreign_key => 'team_a_id'` (and the same for :team_b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just define a private method on `Match` that delegates to the method on `Team` (otherwise, how would it know *which* team to run the method on? You say it's an instance method, and I assume a match has teams that are playing it).

```
after_save :update_teams_goals_sum
after_destroy :update_teams_goals_sum

private

def update_teams_goals_sum
  [team_a, team_b].each &:goals_sum
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I also had to correct a wrong part of the 'goals sum' definition in team.rb model, since it was using a wrong "unless" conditional that prevented the :goal_count_cache column in db to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
after_save :notify_team
after_destroy :notify_team

private

def notify_team
  Team.goals_sum
end
```

Comment: That's not calling an *instance* method of Team.

Comment: @Alex Lang - That would give me this error: _undefined method `goals_sum' for #<Class:0xb6f61344>_

Comment: well, you still have to define `def self.goals_sum` on `Team`.