# Rails: Calling or delegate instance method from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is to call or to delegate an instance method from another model

Here are two similar questions: [Ruby on Rails: Calling an instance method from another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278113/ruby-on-rails-calling-an-instance-method-from-another-model)

[In rails how can I delegate to a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568211/in-rails-how-can-i-delegate-to-a-class-method)

I have four models associated:

**Order has_many :reservations / belongs_to :order_status**

**OrderStatus has_many :order**

**Reservation belongs_to :order / belongs_to :reservation_status**

**ReservationStatus has_many :reservations**

What I'm trying to do:

**I want to change the reservation_status_id of the reservation when the order status of the order is updated.**

Models:

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :order_status
  has_many :reservations
  after_update :update_reservations

private
  def update_reservations
    if self.order_status_id == 2
      Reservation.update_status_completed
    end  
  end
end
```

**reservation.rb**

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :reservation_status

    def update_status_completed
        self.reservation_status_id = 5
    end 
end
```

**reservation_status.rb**

```
class ReservationStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reservations
end
```

**order_status.rb**

```
class OrderStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end
```

I want to change to reservation_status_id of the reservation to 5 when the order status of the order  is set to 2. But I'm getting an Undefined method error 'update_status_completed'. As I understand rails can't find the update_status_completed that is in the reservation model.

Here's the log:

```
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Reservation Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 85]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "orders" SET "order_status_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "orders"."id" = ?  [["order_status_id", 2], ["updated_at", "2016-03-12 15:24:49.024769"], ["id", 85]]
   (6.0ms)  rollback transaction
NoMethodError: undefined method `update_status_completed' for #<Class:0x2abfbc8>
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Antonio/Desktop/RegiSportV01/regisports/app/models/order.rb:67:in `update_reservations'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_update_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `_update_record'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:70:in `_update_record'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:504:in `create_or_update'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
... 12 levels...
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
        from (irb):7
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'irb(main):008:0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it in a callback function...

inside your model:

```
after_save :update_order_status

def update_order_status
  if # relevant condition
     # do stuff
  end
end
```

you're calling a class method but defining it as an instance method. in order to call:

```
Reservation.update_status
```

update_status needs to be defined as:

```
def self.update_status
```

but when you're calling a class method...you're not going to have access to self, so you won't be able to say

```
self.status_id # or whatever it was
```

that is, you won't be able to call this:

```
Reservation.update_status_completed # calling as class method
```

in one model and do this in another:

```
self.reservation_status_id = 5 # inside that class method trying to use instance
```

because you don't have an instance there to get the status_id from. To fix this, pass the value through an argument to the class method so you're not trying to rely on an object you don't have access to.

EDIT:
Can't tell exactly which reservation you're trying to update but to update all of them:

```
# order.rb
def update_reservations_status
  if self.order_status_id == 2
    self.reservations.each do |reservation|
      reservation.update_status_completed
    end
  end     
end

# reservation.rb
def update_status_completed
   self.reservation_status_id = 5
   self.save
end
```

Now the self in update status completed is referring to an instance...bc we're calling last in update_reservations_status.

Comment: isn't that what I have in my order model?

Comment: oh yeah--update_status needs to be defined as def self.update_status since you're calling it as a class method

Comment: Still not working but I'll keep trying. Thanks for your help

Comment: after an Order...which reservation are you trying to update? How do we know which reservation to update since an order has many reservations?

Not immediately clear from the code what you're trying to do. We need to know which object to update in order to update it. If we know which reservation you're updating it's easy to make this work.

Comment: The order status is changed in the charges controller after successful payment. But I'm testing this in the console at the moment by selecting an order and changing the status.

Comment: my edit will update the last reservation belonging to order

Comment: What about all the reservations belonging to the order? Thanks for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: I don't know the business logic of your app...should all of the reservations belonging to the order be updated? If so, I can edit to do that instead. Edited: see above.